# jQuery Ajax success doesnt run after POST to Django View

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

So i've got a problem I can't figure out. I'm building an application which tracks student attendance. I need the AJAX call to change the DOM and disable a checkbox for a student if they are present. This is supposed to happen after the data about their entrance time is entered into the database.

For clarity:

'#attendance' is the form with the checkboxes'

'input#select_all' is a function which checks all the boxes in the form for convenience

'input#left' is the ID of each of the check boxes. The function call in the success clause of the AJAX call is almost identical to a separate function I built which checks all the boxes, except that it disables those checkboxes (so i doubt this is a problem, and anyway i cant disable the select_all box).

I've got a working ajax call:

```
var frm = $('#attendance');

frm.submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm,
        success: function(data){
            $('input#select_all').prop('disabled',true)
            $('input#left').each(function(){
                if (this.checked == true){
                    this.prop('disabled',true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Which posts to a Django view successfully, and the view updates the attendance table in the database:

```
def incoming(request):
    data = request.POST
    class_name = request.POST['class_name']
    list = [x for x in data.iterlists() if x[1][0] == 'on']
    names = [str(x[0]) for x in list]
    c = Class.objects.get(title=class_name)
    for x in names:
        n = Student.objects.get(name=x)
        attendance_query = Attendance.objects.get(class_instance=c.id, student=n.id)
        attendance_query.student_present = timezone.now()
        attendance_query.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

The whole thing works great! Except when the ajax call is all said and done it does NOT call the success functions. Basically it seems that even though it gets an HTTP response, the ajax call still thinks it has not succeeded. Are there any thoughts on how I can make this thing work?

I basically want the present student's checkboxes to be disabled so they cant have their attendance updated with a false time. And I also want to disable the select_all checkbox cause it can still select disabled checkboxes.

So how the heck to i get my AJAX call to run its success function? I'm baffled.

Some things I have tried:

Changed success function to take parameter as an input. This did something, except that it just sent the browser to a blank page, which defeats the purpose of having an ajax call.

EDIT: So I added a separate function which does dom effects after the button is clicked. I should have done this earlier, and i sort of needlessly complicated the ajax call. However, i would still like to know why the success functions werent running.

Comment: I think this happen do to Csrftoken. if you going to send form by post method you have to must pass csrftoken with form data.

Comment: Well the CSRF token is in the form, and when I look at the post data sent by the ajax call, it's definitley in there.

Comment: Remove `return false;` Replace `return HttpResponse(status=200)` with `HttpResponse()` and try alerting after `success(data)`

Comment: @user2032220 the only way to get the ajax call to stop going to the /incoming page is to have a satus=204 response (the code is wrong there, i'll fix it). So HttpResponse() does the same thing - sends you to the blank incoming/ page. Also, if i replace the code in the success function with an alert, that doesn't fire either.

Comment: Try this 
data =  frm.serialize()
and then pass data

Comment: @Yogesh Tried that, nothing happened. I think im gonna approach the problem differently. Gonna attach the DOM effects to the button click and see how it works out.